# Which hardware cannot be accessed by web-based apps?

Tags: html5, web-application

Everyone is saying that hybrid apps are better than web-based app, because, for example, a web-based app has hard time accessing the phone's hardware. But it seems HTML5 apps can access easily the camera, file system, GPS and so on. So I really want to know which hardware a web-based app cannot access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to list all devices that can't be accessed by webpages because there's an infinite number of devices that can potentially exist. You can only list stuff that webpages *can* access.

I also guess that you're not asking only for hardware, because for example file system isn't hardware (and it's not true that webpages can access it, by the way). I'll also list other stuff that seems related and is available to webpages.

Here's an incomplete list of things webpages *can* do:

- Use your camera and microphone
- Check your geographical location
- Store files in private, isolated storage
- Read touch screen events
- Play sounds and videos (limited set of supported formats)
- Run sandboxed processes (web workers) and communicate with them
- Use GPU-accelerated graphics
- Read files you have explicitly selected
- Communicate with other webpages that explicitly allow these connections

And here's an incomplete list of things webpages *can't* do:

- Read/write arbitrary files to/from file system
- List file system directories
- Read path of explicitly selected files (possible in theory, in practice blocked by browsers)
- Access hard disk/storage device (ie. read raw data, set partitions etc.)
- Communicate with any site on the Internet through HTTP(S)
- Communicate with any server on the Internet through any protocol (but HTTP connection can be switched to any protocol via web socket)
- Enumerate screens
- Determine kind of connected screens and their parameters (resolution etc.)
- Draw anywhere on the screen (limited to web browser's window)
- Access GPU (ie. use all of its features, including GPGPU)
- Interact with native processes
- Interact with operating system
- Enumerate connected devices
- Access printer (limited printing support is provided by browser)